# html5 form submission issue

Tags: javascript, forms, html, button

I have a piece of javascript which is initialized on the click of a button, and takes information from a form input to perform geolocation etc based on the data.
The issue I am having is that I have to place the button outside of the form in the html, otherwise when it is clicked, no javascript is fired!
This of course means that my users cannot hit enter in the offending text box (as they lose their data!)
Is there a way I can stop this from happening and be able to include the button in the form?

The HTML is:

```
<form>
<input id="addyInput" placeholder="Don't forget postcode!" size="25"> 
</form>
<button id="start" onclick="initialize()">Find Me!</button>
```

I can also include some of the javascript if needs be!  (although that works fine!) :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the javascript.  Needs be.

Comment: Why does the button need to be outside the form? Why wouldn't JavaScript fire? How are you detecting it? Why would users lose data if they hit Enter? Your description is remarkably vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use :

```
<button id="start" onclick="return initialize()">Find Me!</button>
```

and then make sure initialize() returns false.

Comment: Thankyou that worked perfectly!  Just for reference (I'm still quite new to javascript programming) why do the functions called by the buttons need to return when in a form?

Comment: What you are saying, is on click, take no action.  That is what return false means.  It's normal action would be to submit the form.